# SQL SERVER SSIS Deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence, ssis-2012

I am new to the BI Section. I have created a parametric SQL Report through SQL Server Reporting Services and deployed over the local server. Post this, I could view my reports over Internet explorer. Similarly, I have deployed the SSIS package on my server. But I can't get any URL where the SSIS package has been deployed. Is there any method through which I can publish this SSIS package?

Comment: You are using Project Deployment Model or Package Deployment Model?

Comment: I am using project deployment model

Comment: Then your entire project was deployed to your SSIS catalog. Connect to your server with SSMS and look for Integration Services Catalogs.

Comment: Yes, it is deployed to the SSIS catalog. I can even execute it from the SSMS itself. But can I publish it somehow to a local server?

Comment: You can execute it, yes. Just go to your package, right-click,Execute. You can also setup Jobs and run the packages directly from your Catalog. If you want to run your packages from filesystem you will have to copy them yourself to the server. Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your help mxix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107543/discussion-between-anshul-dubey-and-mxix).